# Any ideas on how to remove small abandoned pixel in a png using OpenCV or other algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing

I got a png image like this:

[image]

The blue color is represent transparent. And all the circle is a pixel group. So, I would like to find the biggest one, and remove all the small pixel, which is not group with the biggest one. In this example, the biggest one is red colour circle, and I will retain it. But the green and yellow are to small, so I will remove them. After that, I will have something like this:

[image]
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you consider only the size of objects, use the following algorithm: labellize the connex components of the mask image of the objects (all object pixels are white, transparent ones are black). Then compute the areas of the connex components, and filter them. At this step, you have a label map and a list of authorized labels. You can read the label map and overwrite the mask image with setting every pixel to white if it has an authorized label.

OpenCV does not seem to have a labelling function, but cvFloodFill can do the same thing with several calls: for each unlabeled white pixel, call FloodFill with this pixel as marker. Then you can store the result of this step in an array (of the size of the image) by assigning each newly assigned pixel with its label. Repeat this as long as you have unlabellized pixels.

Else you can recode the connex component function for binary images, this algorithm is well known and easy to implement (maybe start with Matlab's `bwlabel`).

Comment: `cv::drawContours()` with the `CV_FILLED` flag is a built-in way to label the connected components.

Answer (score 0):

The handiest way to filter objects if you have an *a priori* knowledge of their size is to use morphological operators. In your case, with opencv, once you've loaded your image (`OpenCV` supports `PNG`), you have to do an "openning", that is an erosion followed by a dilation.
The small objects (smaller than the size of the structuring element you chose) will disappear with erosion, while the bigger will remain and be restored with the dilation.
(reference [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/image_filtering.html), cv::morphologyEx).
The shape of the big object might be altered. If you're only doing detection, it is harmless, but if you want your object to avoid transformation you'll need to apply a "top hat" transform.